# Error with Character structure

Tags: c#

hey guys so I get this error.[image: Error with 'password']

I have tried changing it from `'Password'` to `"Password"` but it has not effect.

[image: Error with "password"]

here is the code. In case you need it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace InfestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //HASHING PASSWORD
        public sealed class PasswordHash
        {
            const int SaltSize = 16, HashSize = 20, HashIter = 10000;
            readonly byte[] _salt, _hash;
            public PasswordHash(string password)
            {
                new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(_salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
                _hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
            }
            public PasswordHash(byte[] hashBytes)
            {
                Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
                Array.Copy(hashBytes, SaltSize, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
            }
            public PasswordHash(byte[] salt, byte[] hash)
            {
                Array.Copy(salt, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
                Array.Copy(hash, 0, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
            }
            public byte[] ToArray()
            {
                byte[] hashBytes = new byte[SaltSize + HashSize];
                Array.Copy(_salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
                Array.Copy(_hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, HashSize);
                return hashBytes;
            }
            public byte[] Salt { get { return (byte[])_salt.Clone(); } }
            public byte[] Hash { get { return (byte[])_hash.Clone(); } }
            public bool Verify(string password)
            {
                byte[] test = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < HashSize; i++)
                    if (test[i] != _hash[i])
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void main_B_Signup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegWindow rWindow = new RegWindow();
            rWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        private void main_B_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Store a password hash
            PasswordHash shhh = new PasswordHash(Main_T_Password.Text);
            byte[] hashBytes = shhh.ToArray();

            //connect to the database
            SqlConnection loginConn = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            loginConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=Production; " + "connection timeout=30");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username, Password FROM [User] WHERE Username =@UsernameValue", loginConn);
            loginConn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UsernameValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Main_T_Username.Text;
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dt['Password'] == hashBytes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("username and Password = Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password = Wrong");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("username and Password = incorrect");

            }
            loginConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of C is this?

Comment: C# i did tag it :D

Comment: Perhaps use a string literal for a literal string, instead of a character literal. `"` rather than `'`'.

Comment: `"Password"` instead of `'Password'` (please note, *quotation marks*)

Comment: If you read up i did say i have tried that..

Comment: "Password" cannot be used with `DATATABLE`

Comment: You seem to completely fail to understand what "has no effect" means. The error message you get now, it is different, no?

Comment: yes it does have different error. it was working yesterday with `'password'` dont see how after saving and opening it up the morning it stopped working.

Comment: You are trying to access a **row** in your DataTable but access the DataTable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the issue :|

`if ((string)dt.Rows[0]["Password"] == Main_T_Password.Text)`

it works because its plain text, I was hashing the password

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace InfestApp
{
    public sealed class PasswordHash
    {
        const int SaltSize = 16, HashSize = 20, HashIter = 10000;
        readonly byte[] _salt, _hash;
        public PasswordHash(string password)
        {
            new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(_salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
            _hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
        }
        public PasswordHash(byte[] hashBytes)
        {
            Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
            Array.Copy(hashBytes, SaltSize, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
        }
        public PasswordHash(byte[] salt, byte[] hash)
        {
            Array.Copy(salt, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
            Array.Copy(hash, 0, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
        }
        public byte[] ToArray()
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = new byte[SaltSize + HashSize];
            Array.Copy(_salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
            Array.Copy(_hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, HashSize);
            return hashBytes;
        }
        public byte[] Salt { get { return (byte[])_salt.Clone(); } }
        public byte[] Hash { get { return (byte[])_hash.Clone(); } }
        public bool Verify(string password)
        {
            byte[] test = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < HashSize; i++)
                if (test[i] != _hash[i])
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void main_B_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Store a password hash
            PasswordHash shhh = new PasswordHash(Main_T_Password.Text);
            byte[] hashBytes = shhh.ToArray();

            //connect to the database
            //connect to the database
            SqlConnection loginConn = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            loginConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=Production; " + "connection timeout=30");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username, Password FROM [User] WHERE Username =@UsernameValue", loginConn);
            loginConn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UsernameValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Main_T_Username.Text;
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // access the first row (index=0) and access the row's column by name
                if ((string)dt.Rows[0]["Password"] == Main_T_Password.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("username and Password = Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password = Wrong");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WrongPass or Username!");



                loginConn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void main_B_Signup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegWindow rWindow = new RegWindow();
            rWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }





        private void Main_T_Username_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Main_T_Username.Text == "Username")
                Main_T_Username.Text = "";
        }

        private void Main_T_Username_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Main_T_Username.Text == "")
                Main_T_Username.Text = "Username";
        }

        private void Main_T_Password_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Main_T_Password.Text == "Password")
                Main_T_Password.Text = "";
        }

        private void Main_T_Password_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Main_T_Password.Text == "")
                Main_T_Password.Text = "Password";
        }
    }
}
```

if you see here

```
        PasswordHash shhh = new PasswordHash(Main_T_Password.Text);
        byte[] hashBytes = shhh.ToArray();
```

I was setting

`if ((string)dt.Rows[0]["Password"] == hashBytes)`

trying to read the stored Password hash

Answer (score 0):

A char represents only one character:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit.
```

You should use another type, like string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the DataTable, you need to access the DataRow:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // access the first row (index=0) and access the row's column by name
    if ((string)dt.Rows[0]["Password"] == hashBytes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("username and Password = Correct");
    }
}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'byte[]' InfestApp c:\users\custardwork\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\InfestApp\InfestApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs 92 Active

Comment: that is the error now. >.< i dont get how i did not do anything but save and yesterday it was working.